# Trello Card - Label Color, PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm new in here and extremely basic in PHP.

I got my script working except for the label color part (I'm surely putting the color in the wrong format, I don't even know what I am doing):

```
    $URL    = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards"; // works
    $Key    = "LongKeyhere"; // works (Censored)
    $Token  = "EvenLongerKeyHere"; // works (Censored)
    $Pos    = "top"; // works
    $Name   = "Hello world"; // works
    $Desc   = "Description"; // works
    $Label  = [blue];  // Nope, I tried "blue" too and didn't work
    $IdList = "564f70443XXXXXXXXXXX"; // Posts here, (Censored)
    $fields = "key=$Key&token=$Token&pos=$Pos&name=$Name&desc=$Desc&labels=$Label&idList=$IdList"; // works
```

Here are some links that might help you guys helping me:

https://developers.trello.com/apis
https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/label

The working JSON Body looks like this:

```
{"desc":"Description","labels":["red"],"pos":"top","idList":"564f70443XXXXXXXXXXX","name":"Hello world"}
```

Now my question is, what do I have to do to the $Label variable for it to work? 'red' and 'yellow' are examples of working colors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Trello API, but [this](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/label#post-1-labels) would suggest you need something like:-

```
$label = ['color' => 'blue'];
```

Comment: OK, but you are looking for something along those lines.